# json C# 7 Tuple Support

Tags: json, tuples, c#-7.0

I want to get my C#7 tuple property names in my JSON (Newtonsoft.Json) output.
My problem is:
When I want to convert my tuple to JSON format that not support my parameters names.

For example this is my "Test2" method and you can see the JSON output:

```
public void Test2()
{
    var data = GetMe2("ok");
    var jsondata = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);//JSON output is {"Item1":5,"Item2":"ok ali"}
}

public (int MyValue, string Name) GetMe2(string name)
{
    return (5, name + " ali");
}
```

The JSON output is "{"Item1":5,"Item2":"ok ali"}" but i want "{"MyValue":5,"Name":"ok ali"}";

This is not impossible because I can get property names in runtime:

```
foreach (var item in this.GetType().GetMethods())
{
    dynamic attribs = item.ReturnTypeCustomAttributes;
    if (attribs.CustomAttributes != null && attribs.CustomAttributes.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var at in attribs.CustomAttributes)
        {
            if (at is System.Reflection.CustomAttributeData)
            {
                var ng = ((System.Reflection.CustomAttributeData)at).ConstructorArguments;
                foreach (var ca in ng)
                {
                    foreach (var val in (IEnumerable<System.Reflection.CustomAttributeTypedArgument>)ca.Value)
                    {
                        var PropertyNameName = val.Value;
                        Console.WriteLine(PropertyNameName);//here is property names of C#7 tuple
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        dynamic data = attribs.CustomAttributes[0];
        var data2 = data.ConstructorArguments;
    }

}
```

Comment: https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1230

Comment: Ah I see it's your issue as well. In general, such library-specific questions are more likely to be answered at GitHub issue-tracker than at StackOverflow. We only can help you with implementing some sort of custom method or crutch solution.

Comment: Why ask a Stack Overflow question *after* you've already found it's not implemented in Json.NET yet, and that there's a feature request?

Comment: yes i see that befor add question ty.

Comment: i hope anyone can change json opensource project in my case,because i can get parameters name in runtime,i think json component must update to new version to support that

Comment: "i hope anyone can change json opensource project in my case". Is there a reason why you can't be that "anyone"? Grab the source, make the change and submit a PR, rather than waiting for someone else to do it for you.

Comment: @AliYousefie It is an open-source project. You can do it yourself, introduce and test this functionality and then pull request it to Newtonsoft.Json repository to help other people.

Comment: yes i can try this but this is my first time to read all of the json source and change it mybe that can be hard for me.because i dont know what json component doing now.

Comment: also i ask it mybe anyone solve this befor me.

Answer (score 2):

For the specific case here, it is impossible. That's because `SerializeObject` has no way of finding out where the tuple came from, all it sees is `ValueTuple<int, string>`.

The situation would be different if you were serializing an object with tuple properties, in which case `SerializeObject` could use reflection to find the `TupleElementNames` attributes (even though it currently doesn't).

Comment: isn't the `TupleElementNames` applied only to the return value of methods?

Comment: @PauloMorgado [It's applied to properties and fields too.](https://sharplab.io/#f:r/MYGwhgzhAEDC0G8CwAoa7oAoIBcBOAlgHYDm0RYAtgKYA00xO0YJ1AlNAAp4D2ADtTw4AnomiscAbmgRqU6AF9UGLLkKlyVOgyJMW7aADEC1EABNJqBUA===)

Comment: I was including properties in "methods". I did forgot to mention fields. Nevertheless, it's attached to the origin of the tuple, not the tuple itself. Special handling by a serializer could happen but would you recommend it? I wouldn't.

Comment: I am not sure whether it's impossible. For example, you can supply Dapper with a tuple and it will successfully return an IEnumerable of populated tuple. I am not sure why Newtonsoft is not able to do the same thing.

Comment: @Zorthgo The problem here is that JSON.NET can't read the *names* of the tuple fields. Presumably, Dapper relies on the order of the fields, not their names.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer it that tuples don't have properties.

A tuple is a bag of values used, mainly, to return multiple values from a method.

They were never intended to model entities.

The only way to solve your problem, if you don't want to create a type for that, is:

```
public void Test2()
{
    var data = GetMe2("ok");
    var jsondata = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { data.MyValue, data.Name });//JSON output is {"Item1":5,"Item2":"ok ali"}
}
```

Comment: You can serialize fields, but tuples hae no named fields, it's just Item1, Item2 etc. The names are "just" compiler magic

Comment: Does this code really solve the problem? OP; desired output is `{"MyValue":5,"Name":"ok ali"}`